# video js on slick carousel makes control bar uncomplete width

Tags: jquery, html, slider, video.js, slick.js

I have [Video Js](https://videojs.com/) plugin inside [slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) so basically, it's a video slider. the video controls is not complete when clicking next or prevoius. Any Idea what happened? both desktop and mobile have the same issue. not always but there are time that when you click next/prev it appears.

[image: Here's the desktop image]
[image: Here's for mobile]

Please Help.

oh and I'm using `jquery-1.11.2.min.js`

Here's my current confiquration for slick next/prev event

```
$('.slick-arrow').click(function() {
    (".vjs-has-started video").each(function (){
       this.load();
    });
    $('.video-js').removeClass('vjs-playing');
      if ($(window).width() < 600) {
         $('.vjs-big-play-button').hide();
      }
      else {
          $('.vjs-big-play-button').show();
      }
 });
```

Comment: Can you create a CodePen/JSFiddle etc.? It's probably something to do with Video.js not being able to detect the size of slides off-screen.

Comment: I know this is old, but i'm having the same issue. were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on some sites. І had this problem when my style.css had property `body{overflox-x:hidden;}`. I changed this property and slider work correctly.